# How to use QProcess in headless script?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside, qprocess

I'm trying to run another application and get its output from Stdout with this script:

```
p = QtCore.QProcess()
p.start("./mainapp.exe", [])
out = p.readAllStandardOutput()

logging.info("Test 2, output: {}".format(out))
```

however, I get this error when running:

```
QProcess: Destroyed while process is still running.
```

Comment: `p` object gets destroyed before the `mainapp.exe` process terminates.

Comment: but even if I put a `time.sleep` after `out = p.readAllStandardOutput()` the same result happens!

Comment: right. that's because it slept for some time, then it destroyed `p` while `mainapp.exe` still was running. the only time this won't happen, it's if `mainapp.exe` terminates before `p` goes out of scope and therefore gets destroyed, printing the debug message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to [wait for the process to finish](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qprocess.html#waitForFinished) before you allow the script to exit:

```
p.start("./mainapp.exe", [])
p.waitForFinished()
out = p.readAllStandardOutput()
```